Locally uniform convergence of given series
Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{z+n} $ converges locally uniformly on the set $\mathbb{C}  \setminus \{-n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.
I dont know that to do here. I have tried to rewrite this series to look a like power series but this really didnt work. Any help is appreciated.
I have also tried to use the following criterion for uniform convergence (which obviously implies loc. unf. convergence): If $f_n$ is a sequence of complex functions that converges uniformly to zero and the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |f_{n+1} - f
_n|$ converges uniformly. Then for every sequence $a_n$ with bounded sequence of partial sums, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nf_n$ converges uniformly.
This doesnt seem to apply because im unable to show that $f_n$ converges uniformly to zero and that series of differences converges uniformly.
Thanks in advance.

Hints:
STEP I
It is enough to show that $\sum [\frac {(-1)^{n}} {n+z}-\frac {(-1)^{n}} n]$ is locally uniformly convergent for  which it is enough to show that $\sum \frac {(-1)^{n}} {n(n+z)}$ is locally uniformly convergent.
STEP II
It is enough to show that $\sum [\frac {(-1)^{n}} {n(n+z)}-\frac {(-1)^{n}} {n^{2}}]$ is locally uniformly convergent.
STEP II
Use the fact that $|n+z|$ is bounded below on any compact set disjoint from $\{-1,-2,...\}$ to see that M-test applies to above series.

Ok so just for short clarification: You are using this criterion for uniform convergence, but instead of uniform convergence of the series of differences, you show locally uniform convergence. Are you sure that from there you can conclude loc. unf. convergence of the given series? (obviously (-1)^n has a bounded seq. of partial sums and you want to show loc unf. convergence by showing compact convergence)

Locally uniform convergence on $\Omega$ is same as uniform convergence on every compact subset of $\Omega$. I am therefore restricting myself to a compact subset of the given domain. @LucDesombre

Im sorry i really dont understand how you get these different series. For example how does locally uniform convergence of the first series you wrote imply loc unf convergence of the given series?

If $\sum [f_n(z)-g_n(z)]$ and $\sum g_n(z)$ are locally uniformly convergent so is $\sum f_n(z)$. The series $\sum \frac {(-1)^{n}} n$ is locally uniformly convergent because it is a series of constants and it is convergent by Alternating series test. @LucDesombre

I might add i dont get how your second series arrives. Adding two terms in your first series leaves me with a z with I miss in your second series.

@luc.1401 I am omitting the factor of $z$ because local uniform convergence of $\sum f_n(z)$ automatically implies  local uniform convergence of $\sum zf_n(z)$. You only need boundedness of compact sets to justify this.

Dont you need like $f_n >= 0 $ to justify that?

No, why do you need that?

Trying to prove ur last comment: suppose the sum over the $f_n$ converges loc. unf. and i want to show that the series over $zf_n$ converges loc. unf., for that Suppose$ K$ is compact then there exists $C>0$ s.t. $|zf_n(z)| <= C|f_n|$ but I dont know anything about the convergence of the sum over $C|f_n|$

The partial sums $S_n(Z)$ of $\sum f_n(z)$ converge uniformly to some $S(z)$. Now $zS_n(z)-zS(z) \to 0$ uniformly because $z$ is bounded on the compact set. @luc.1401

Oh of course, i see. Ty

I was now able to write down the whole thing. Thank you for all the comments!
